# I'm I affecting the values? or the references? Removing multiple Observers without a LifeCycleOwner

Tags: java, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, observer-pattern

I want to be able to connect different `LiveData<X>` to the same `Observer`.
Up to now, my little module has been working extremely fine as hell, but to avoid linking the `ViewModel` to a `LifecycleOwner`, I included a way for the module to use the `.observeForever()` function if owner is null,

The observers are wrapped inside a bigger one that stores an `int` value that declares if the onChange() on each of the LiveData<>'s is the first one or not... this was done because in some cases I needed to ignore the initial onChange() callback.

Because there may be many observers (Keeping track of this int value)... depending on the amount of `LiveData<X>` ("sources" as the docs call them), it was easy for me to clear all the observers with the `liveData.removeObservers(owner);` function, automatically clearing all the observers at that specific owner.

But because the owner is null, now I need to keep a reference to all the observers in a single one, and remove THEM by name `liveData.removeObserver(observer);`

My first concern is that by declaring `new` on each iteration, I'm losing the reference to that observer forever.

If that's the case I can remove the Observer inside the wrapper, which is, as intended, the same among all observers, BUT the first thing that comes intuitively to mind, is that the obvious thing to do is not to destroy the most inner observer, but the outer one, because that destroys the inner one as well.

The problem is that the outer ones are different, while the inner one is the one that is common, so:

Which one should I remove, and How should they be declared?

```
private RunTimeObserverWrapper<? super T> runTimeObserverWrapper;
/*This is the recent change I made in the hopes of being able to remove it/them */


private void connectObservers(
        List<LiveData<T>> liveDatas,
        boolean ignoreInitialization
) {


    this.listLiveData = liveDatas;

    Observer<? super T> itemObserver = itemObserverInitializer();
    /*This is the common observer*/


    for (LiveData<T> liveData: listLiveData
         ) {
        if (!liveData.hasObservers()) {

            runTimeObserverWrapper = new RunTimeObserverWrapper<>(ignoreInitialization, itemObserver);
            /*This is the recent change I made placing it as a field variable*/
            
//                RunTimeObserverWrapper<? super T> runTimeObserverWrapper = new RunTimeObserverWrapper<>(ignoreInitialization, itemObserver);
                /*This was working as intended, but I want to disassociate the module from the LifeCycleOwner*/


            if (owner != null) {
                liveData.observe(
                        owner,
                        runTimeObserverWrapper
                );
            } else {
                liveData.observeForever(
                        runTimeObserverWrapper
                );
            }
            /*New Snippet*/

//                liveData.observe(
//                        owner,
//                        runTimeObserverWrapper
//                );
                /*Old snippet*/

        }

    }
}

public void destroyObserversAndList() {

    for (LiveData<T> liveData: listLiveData
         ) {

//            liveData.removeObservers(owner);
            /*This was correctly removing ALL Observers*/
        
        if (owner != null) {
            liveData.removeObservers(owner);
        } else {
            liveData.removeObserver(runTimeObserverWrapper);
        }
        /*This is the new snippet to account for a lack of LifeCycleOwner*/
    }

    listLiveData.clear();
}
```

So, as you can see, my concern is that by calling `liveData.removeObserver(runTimeObserverWrapper);`, I''ll only be removing the last observer defined by `new` inside the iteration.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a lot harder than I first realized.
Primarily, because the answer was found by solving a secondary unrelated problem: the Database would at times return an empty value for the table in which all the rows in it were erased, and my list differ module, didnt knew what type of list it should erase.

The solution to this problem helped solve 2 problems at once, maybe a 3rd one, and one of them was the problem mentioned above.

The solution was to wrap both: the LiveData with its own Observer, now both should be given an Id, so that its answer could be stored with its Id in a LinkedHashMap.
If the answer was empty, it would just store the empty list with its corresponding Id, erasing the previous value.

Now that the LiveData was bundled with its own Observer, I could make a method that could release it from its own Observer, and, by iterating throught each LiveDataWrapper, I could call this method and remove them.

```
public void destroyObserversAndList() {

    if (listLiveData != null) {
        for (LiveDataSourceWrapper<T> liveData: listLiveData
        ) {

            liveData.removeObserver();

        }
        listLiveData.clear();


    }

}
```

And the LiveDataSourceWrapper class:

```
public class LiveDataSourceWrapper<X> {

    private int liveDataId;
    private SourceObserverWrapper<X> identityLiveDataObserver;
    private LiveData<X> liveData;


    public LiveDataSourceWrapper(
            LiveData<X> liveData,
            int liveDataId
    ) {
        this.liveData = liveData;
        this.liveDataId = liveDataId;
    }

    public void observeForever(@NonNull SourceObserver<X> observer) {

        identityLiveDataObserver = new SourceObserverWrapper<X>(liveDataId, observer);
        liveData.observeForever(identityLiveDataObserver);

    }

    public void removeObserver() {
        liveData.removeObserver(identityLiveDataObserver);


    }


    public boolean hasObservers() {
        return liveData.hasObservers();
    }

}
```